# CCnet email publisher username case-sensitivity

Tags: svn, email, configuration, cruisecontrol.net, case-sensitive

I'm using the email publisher of CCnet 1.6.7981 and SVN as version control system. My problem is that the SVN usernames are not case-sensitive but the CCnet email publisher is. So I'm using a dirty workaround in my configuration as everyone has a 3 letter username:

```
<email from="ccnet@domain.com" mailhost="..." includeDetails="TRUE">
    <users>
        <user name="abc" address="ABCforename.surname@domain.com" />
        <user name="Abc" address="ABCforename.surname@domain.com" />
        <user name="ABc" address="ABCforename.surname@domain.com" />
        <user name="ABC" address="ABCforename.surname@domain.com" />

        <user name="def" address="DEFforename.surname@domain.com" />
        <user name="Def" address="DEFforename.surname@domain.com" />
        <user name="DEf" address="DEFforename.surname@domain.com" />
        <user name="DEF" address="DEFforename.surname@domain.com" />
    </users>
    <modifierNotificationTypes>
        <NotificationType>Failed</NotificationType>
        <NotificationType>Fixed</NotificationType>
        <NotificationType>Exception</NotificationType>
    </modifierNotificationTypes>
</email>
```

Is there a neat solution for this kind of issue?

Comment: Yes - use the same usernames for SVN and email, so that you can simply add "@domain.com" and get a valid email address.

Comment: No, that's not an option. The usernames are the same for every service in my company (including subversion) and there's no way to change them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the converters element
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Email_Publisher
there is an ldap converter and a regex converter

Comment: It seems that I would have to configure every single email address within the replace element as it doesn't change the username (e.g. to lowercase letters) and compare them with the user list. And I couldn't use the <groups> feature anymore.